# Declare sparse array in coffeescript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, sparse-array

In Javascript I can declare a sparse array like:

```
a = [, 1]
```

But that gives an error in Coffeescript. So how can I create sparse arrays in Coffeescript?

I want to do it in a single assignment and not like:

```
a = []
a[1] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not possible.
But you can always [embed javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded):

```
`a = [, 1]`
```

Comment: Or maybe `a = \`[, 1]\``